# Mysql conditional case query - finding out how many rows each condition returned

Tags: php, mysql

Please take a look at this conditional mysql query:

```
SELECT attr1,attr2,attr3 FROM table 
WHERE 
( attr1 LIKE '%cond1%' OR attr1 LIKE '%cond2%' ) 
OR 
( attr2 BETWEEN '30' AND '45' ) 
OR 
( attr3 IN ('cond3') AND attr3 = 'cond4' AND attr3 BETWEEN '18' AND '30' ) 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN ( attr1 LIKE '%cond1%' OR attr1 LIKE '%cond2%' ) THEN 1 
WHEN ( attr2 BETWEEN '30' AND '45' ) THEN 2 
ELSE 3 
END
```

Is there a way I can get with mysql and php the number of rows each condition returns? Or at lease condition 3?

I need a way to know that condition 3 returned 200 rows, for example and store this value into a php variable.

Comment: You should run two different queries to get both the data and the count of the results of one of your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` with `SUM` (or `COUNT` using `NULL` as the `ELSE` result) as an expression to `SELECT`. Using the examples you've given above, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN attr1 LIKE '%cond1%' OR attr1 LIKE '%cond2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition1count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN attr2 BETWEEN '30' AND '45' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition2count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN attr3 IN ('cond3') AND attr3 = 'cond4' AND attr3 BETWEEN '18' AND '30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition3count
FROM
    table
...
```

Keep in mind, however, that depending the content of the data some rows may match more than one of the 3 conditions, and so the total of the 3 counts may be greater than the number of rows returned.